# How can I remove all non-letter (all languages) and non-numeric characters from a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've been searching for quite some time now yet I can not find any explanation on the subject.

If I have a string, say: `u'àaeëß35+{}"´'`. I want all non-alphanumeric charachters removed (however, I want `à, ë, ß` etc. kept.

I'm fairly new to Python and I could not figure out a regex to perform this task.
Only other solution I can think of is having a list with the chars I want to remove and iterating through the string replacing them.

What is the correct Pythonic solution here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
In [63]: s = u'àaeëß35+{}"´'

In [64]: print ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalnum())
àaeëß35
```

Comment: Hi @root! Excellent solution! Thank you very much! If I want to keep spaces should I just add or c == ' ' to the end?

Comment: @Phil -- yes, adding `or c == ' '` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
def StripNonAlpha(s):
    return "".join(c for c in s if c.isalpha())
```

Comment: it removes the numbers as well.